# Discontinuities with an oscillating function in the denominator

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

The problem is to find the discontinuities in the following function

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{4x+1}{5cos(\frac{x}{2})+1}
\end{equation}

I know the function will be discontinuous whenever $5cos(x/2)+1 = 0$. This gives
\begin{align}
5\cos(x/2)+1 &= 0\\
\cos(x/2) &= -1/5 \\
x &= 2\cos^{-1}(-1/5)\\
\end{align}

However, since cosine oscillates, I know there should be discontinuities for x every $2\pi$ radians. How do I take this into account in my soltion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\cos(x/2) = -1/5$ has two solutions in the interval $(-2\pi, 2\pi)$ and that the period of $\cos(x/2)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{1/2} = 4\pi$. Hence, the general solution is:
$$
x = 4\pi n \pm 2\cos^{-1}(1/5)
$$
where $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!